# A data design question of labeling sides in a battle game

Tags: database, algorithm, design-patterns, data-structures, database-design

I am designing a chess-like game but I believe this question can be extend to all games that have battle.

> So my question is, how should I properly label an object as a `friend`
>   object or an `enemy` object in a battle game?

Take chess for example. If **player W** plays white pieces, then **W**'s opponent, **player B**, plays black pieces.

For **W**, all white pieces are `friend` objects and black pieces are `enemy` objects, while **player B** has black `friends` and white `enemies`. So here my labeling problem can be simply solved by using colors. When you try to calculate the possible moves of a piece and decide if you can take out a piece, you can basically check if they have the distinct colors.

However, what if two players have the same view? For example, a game can color all `friends` as black while color all `enemies` as white, and the players start their games with their pieces all at the bottom. In this sense of speaking, indeed, pieces can be viewed as the **attributes** of the player. So the coloring of black and white is based on whether a piece has an owner id that is the same as yours.

Here comes a problem:

> Although I can decide the color by comparing the ids, what if I want
>   to know whether a `friend` piece enters the `enemy region`?

The definition of `enemy region` could be the upper part of the board. Since board is not part of the player (while pieces can be), it is not possible to use the previous id solution.

So one possible solution I can think of is to make the board an **attribute** of the **player**. However, there are two players, this **doubles** the data storage because we have actually only one board from an objective perspective. And any moves and further changes on a piece requires operations on two boards, which is also time consuming.

In order not to **double** the board, I try use to another strategy, which is to use a **landscape view**. What I mean is that, the data doesn't take sides as players. Players view the board from **bottom** to **top**, which is like the  **portrait view**, while data can be viewed from **left to right/right to left** like what a just referee observes. So the data becomes **objective** here. But the problem is how to present the objective data in a subjective manner to players? And it is still not easy to know if a piece enters enemy region.

> So my question is, how should I properly design the data structure, so that it does not doubles or triples or copies multiple times of the data, and in the meanwhile, it is also easy to know the labels of a public area? In my question, the public area is a chess board, where all pieces should fight on this single board. I call it **public** because both players can move their pieces to everywhere on the board, and third parties can also see what's going on the board. But the labels of pieces are just subjective attributes, personal **private** thoughts.

I am not sure if I can properly explain/phrasing my question well so I didn't search for a similar question. Sorry for my laziness. If there is a duplicate question that has been asked, please guide me to it.

---Update---

I think a more clearer question is, let's say I have 3 * 3 board. If I need to move my piece from (1, 2) to (2, 3), then in the perspective of my opponent, the move is not taking place at the same location. It is the opposite. It is from (3, 2) to (2, 1). What is the best way to store this move? Do I have to take one side (subjective) to store it, or is there a neutral/objective way to do this?

The drawback of the subjective way for me is that I need to recalculate the moves for another player to fit his/her view. Using a neutral way might be a life saver.

Comment: Aren't you overthinkig this? You have a model of the game with pieces that can have an owner id and a board with tiles/cells that can also have an owner id. Then you have a view, which is a representation of the model from a particular perspective. Changing that perspective doesn't change the model, but making a move in the game does.

Comment: @MOehm Let's say I have 3 * 3 board. If I have need to move my piece from for example (1, 2) to (2, 3), then in the perspective of my opponent, the move is not taking place at the same location. It is the opposite. It is from (3, 2) to (2, 1). How do you think I should store this move? I am thinking of what could be a neutral way to store this.

Comment: saving the subjective view is like preformatting the data. You avoid computation upon retrieval at the sake of storage space. Should the computation be very expensive, this may be ok. For applying a horizontal symmetry, likely __not__. On the other side, you may want to dupplicate the data on each player (denormalization) and applying the computation on each side might be acceptable. (I definitely would not do it for debugging headaches)

Comment: @user753642 So you are suggesting me choose duplicating data? If you play moba games like dota or lol, then this data will 5 times of the original.

Comment: I am suggesting NOT TO dupplicate the data. Only do it in case of performance need (this is _a priori_ not the case here)

Comment: @Seaky: Choose one global coordinate system, say the one of player1. When you display the board as seen by player1, show it from (1,1) to (3,3) and make player1's  pieces white, player2's pieces black. When you display the board as seen by player1, show it from (3,3) to (1,1) and make player1's  pieces black, player2's pieces white. The global data is not duplicated and is the same for all perspectives, the display isn't. (In this case, the "neutral" way is the perspective of player1, but it doesn't really matter.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A general answer without concrete database design - There is data an there are multiple views. There is no need to copy data but to have multiple references to some data (which of course also takes some memory). E. g. a rook is referenced by a square and by a player. Such references may be stored (collection "enemies") or may be calculated on the fly (collection "reachable") depending on runtime/storage design decisions. Also multiple players are just views. On a game move you have to update all static views while dynamic views need none.

For symmetric games there is the possibility not to store the opponents views but generate them by just transforming the whole game into the other players view with every move. Again this is your decision, stored vs. dynamically created.

Comment: Yeah this is what I am thinking. I just wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

> If I need to move my piece from (1, 2) to (2, 3), then in the perspective of my opponent, the move is not taking place at the same location. It is the opposite. It is from (3, 2) to (2, 1). What is the best way to store this move? Do I have to take one side (subjective) to store it, or is there a neutral/objective way to do this?

Pick one orientation for the board.  It doesn't matter which one you pick.  This *is* a neutral/objective way -- neither choice offers any advantage for either player, and the choice doesn't significantly affect the code.  Any imbalance you imagine, like that it's better to have (0,0) on your own side, is *imaginary*.

This is not a "subjective" choice, it is an "arbitrary" choice.